Add directory to File Manifest using a relative path
How do you add directory to File Manifest with a relative path?
https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io
def make_install(exe):
    files = FileManifest()
    files.add_python_resource(".", exe)

    # sudo code
    templates = glob(["files_dir/**/*"], strip_prefix=".")
    files.add_manifest(templates)
    return files

